# Why does this div overflow when width is 100%?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have created this simple `div` which has a `form`. For some reason its width is greater than 100% of screen even when I've assigned width of 100%.

I've checked for extra margin – I know I'm doing something wrong!

Any ideas?

```css
/* NEWSLETTER SECTION */
.newsletter-wrap {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.newsletter-wrap h4,
.newsletter-wrap label {
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.newsletter-form input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#submit-btn-newsletter {
  text-align: center;
}

#submit-btn-newsletter input {
  background-color: #d02121;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsletter-wrap">
  <div class="newsletter-headline">
    <h4><b> JOIN OUR NEWSLETTER </b></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="newsletter-form">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label> NAME: </label>
        <input type="text">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label>EMAIL: </label>
        <input type="text">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="submit-btn-newsletter">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`padding` created this problem.

```
.newsletter-wrap {
    padding: 2rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem; 
                    ^--------------^----------------------here
    //more code...
 }
```

**insert `box-sizing:border-box;` to `.newsletter-wrap`**

```
.newsletter-wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //more code....
}
```

**OR insert this code :**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
 .newsletter-wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
.newsletter-wrap {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 2rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

 }
 .newsletter-wrap h4, .newsletter-wrap label {
        font-weight: bolder;
        padding-bottom:  1rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

.newsletter-form input {
    padding: 0.5rem;

}
#submit-btn-newsletter  {

    text-align: center;
    }
#submit-btn-newsletter input {
    background-color: #d02121;
    color: white;

}
```

```html
<div class="newsletter-wrap">
    <div class="newsletter-headline">
        <h4><b> JOIN OUR NEWSLETTER </b></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="newsletter-form">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label> NAME: </label>
                <input type="text">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>EMAIL: </label>
                <input type="text">                     
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="submit-btn-newsletter">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">                     
            </fieldset>                 
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

*Read more :*

If you don't use of `box-sizing: border-box;` total width = padding + width + border ,but when use `box-sizing: border-box;` The width properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin.

Comment: Perfect. Can you please explain what/why box-sizing worked?

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing:border-box;` inside `.newsletter-wrap`

```css
/* NEWSLETTER SECTION */
.newsletter-wrap {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 2rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
 box-sizing:border-box;

 }
 .newsletter-wrap h4, .newsletter-wrap label {
        font-weight: bolder;
        padding-bottom:  1rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

.newsletter-form input {
    padding: 0.5rem;

}
#submit-btn-newsletter  {

    text-align: center;
    }
#submit-btn-newsletter input {
    background-color: #d02121;
    color: white;

}
```

```html
<div class="newsletter-wrap">
    <div class="newsletter-headline">
        <h4><b> JOIN OUR NEWSLETTER </b></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="newsletter-form">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label> NAME: </label>
                <input type="text">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label>EMAIL: </label>
                <input type="text">                     
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="submit-btn-newsletter">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">                     
            </fieldset>                 
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what is different between my code and your code? you copy my code only.

Answer (score -1):

You couldve just changed the width to max-width in newsletter-wrap class